# Check if .txt file is up to date

Tags: python, file, http

`Problem`: Suppose you have a `.txt` file with some data and what you want to do is check if said file is up to date with the online database which it was originally downloaded from.

`Answer`: Since the webpage which it was downloaded from is fixed, I would check the Last-Modified tag on the HTTP file and compare it with the file I have on my computer.

`Catch`: If the user has downloaded an older version of the file it would appear on his system that it was created **on the day it was downloaded** and then, when it will be cross-referenced with it's HTTP counterpart it would seem like it's up to date.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the .txt file isn't touched after being downloaded, and that it will only be downloaded from the one HTTP location, then checking the date should be fine.  If you have updated the HTTP file since the download, the .txt file will be older than the HTTP file.

Also, if the file is small, you can just download and replace it instead of just comparing the dates.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be best not to rely on "last modified" date codes, as those can change without the data changing.

The easiest and most full-proof solution would be to download a fresh copy of the data when needed.

More elegant solutions would require you to have control of the webpage.

For example, you could have the current HASH of the text file on the webpage. You could compute the HASH of your local file, compare it with the server's, and then download the file if needed.

Comment: I thought about the first solution you are proposing, and although it's full-proof it does contain a slight risk of overhead to the program. For now the total number of files I need to compile my program is 10-15 files of 2K bytes each, which is nothing. 
But, we are also trying to achieve scalability for our code. Say we want to compute the information on 1000+ files what would happen then?
As to your second solution, can you point me to some implementations about local HASH?